# how scons set link order in building ndk project

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cross-platform, scons

I create a ndk project use STL static library, 
but when I build elf the compiler told error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::Init()', etc.

I found that when the scons build elf it pass stlport.a before a.o so that cause the problem

SO how can I modify SConstruct to put stlport.a after a.o ?

Comment: Please show us how you try to compile/link your sources. Either include the full SConstruct/SConscript, or create an MWE from it. For these kind of beginner questions it might also make more sense to subscribe to the SCons user mailing list (see http://www.scons.org/lists.php ).

Comment: env = Environment(CXX = '/home/xxxx/work/andorid/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++', CC = '/home/xxxx/work/andorid/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++')

Comment: linkflags = " --sysroot=/home/xxxx/work/andorid/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-17/arch-arm -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc /home/xxxx/work/andorid/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a -lgcc -no-canonical-prefixes  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIE -pie -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/xxxx/work/andorid/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/lib "

env.Program("a", ["a.o", "b.o"], LINKFLAGS = linkflags)

Comment: these are the sconstruct file I generated, the scons just put the stl library after a.o and b.o so cause the link order problem, So I want to know how control the order by scons ?

Answer (score 0):

The default link command is defined by the environment variable(s) LINKCOM/SHLINKCOM as:

```
env['LINKCOM'] = '$LINK -o $TARGET $LINKFLAGS $__RPATH $SOURCES $_LIBDIRFLAGS $_LIBFLAGS'
```

(check with "print env.Dump()" in one of your SConscripts if you like)
You can either redefine it, and put the LINKFLAGS after the SOURCES

```
env['LINKCOM'] = '$LINK -o $TARGET $__RPATH $SOURCES $LINKFLAGS $_LIBDIRFLAGS $_LIBFLAGS'
```

or append your static library to the LIBFLAGS variable instead:

```
env.Append(LIBFLAGS=['path_of_static_lib_at_end.a'])
```